# Writing SELECT TOP 1 1 in apache spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How do i write this query in sparksql ?

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = '123'
```

always gives me this error.
mismatched input '1' expecting (line 1, pos 11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keyword "Limit" can be used instead of "Top":

```
SELECT 1 FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = '123' Limit 1
```

Comment: Will it return 1 when it finds some records or will it return the first record ?@pasha701

Comment: in query "SELECT 1", will return 1. If row values required, "SELECT * " can be used.